# invisible chars in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, microsoft-dynamics

I'm using MS SQL Server Report Builder 3.0.

I have Price attribute as currency in Opportunity entity and price as string in Opportunity_Audit entity. When the attribute is transferred, together with it are transferred currency separators, but format changes. My report is based on Opportunity_Audit entity.
When I try to convert Price from string to Int or Double, for example `"20 000 руб."`, I am experiencing problems, because a separator between zeros is not space.
As a fact, it's not a symbol from first 32 ASCII characters. 
When I use

> = Val(Fields!opportunity_audit_price.Value)

the result is 20, but I need 20000. 
Has anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. It was a non-breaking space with UNICODE 160. 
When I removed them, then I convert a string to a number.

```
= Val(Replace(Fields!opportunity_audit_price.Value, StrDup(1, Chr(160)), ""))
```